# $\mathbb{C\otimes_QC} $ is not Noether ring, but $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C\otimes_QC})$ is Noether as topological space

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, noetherian

I once heard that $\mathbb{C}\otimes_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{C} $ is not Noether ring, but $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C}\otimes_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{C})$ is Noether as topological space.

This is probably a last in my memory, but I want to check whether this is true or not.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$I_n = (\zeta_{3^n}\otimes 1-1\otimes \zeta_{3^n})\subset \mathbb{C}\otimes_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{C}$$ It is a strictly increasing chain of ideals.

$$\{ P\in Spec(\mathbb{C}\otimes_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{C}), I_n\subset P\}$$ is a strictly decreasing chain of closed subsets.

Comment: Sorry, then, Spectrum of the ring is not Noether top space. My memory was wrong .  Is $\mathbb{C}\otimes_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{C} $ isomorphic to C×C×C×・・・（ uncountable infinite copies of C）？

Comment: Isomorphic as what ?

Comment: For $K/\Bbb{Q}$ a finite extension then $\Bbb{C}\otimes_\Bbb{Q} K\cong \Bbb{C}^{[K:\Bbb{Q}]}$ as $\Bbb{C}$-algebra but for $K/\Bbb{Q}$ infinite then no as there is no $\sum_j a_j\otimes b_j$ such that $\sum_j a_j\sigma(b_j)=0$ for all but one embedding $\sigma:K\to \Bbb{C}$.

Comment: Then, we cannot find easy form （not using tensor） in this case?

Comment: @reuns What is $\zeta_{3^{n}}$?

Comment: While it is clear to me why that is a striclty increasing chain of ideals, it is not clear to me why that should be a strictly decreasing chain of closed subsets.

Comment: @Jabberwocky For each $3\nmid m$ there is a maximal ideal containing $1\otimes 3^n-3^{nm} \otimes 1$